# How to use if in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to compute the occurrence of a line in a dataframe, but I don’t get the result expected.

ps: `generaldf` is a data.frame, and `userid` is a column of integer

```
y<-0

        for(i in seq_len(nrow(generaldf))) 
        {
          if (generaldf$userid==1) 
            y <-y+1
        }

 return(y)
```

Comment: Are you just trying to count how many times `userid` is equal to 1? `sum(generaldf$userid == 1)` will do that without a `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work get rid of the `return(y)`. return()  is for functions. Here you can just print the result. Either `print(y)` or just `(y)`

Instead of the *for* loop consider summing the logical vector (true = 1, false = 0) mentioned in the comments `sum(generaldf$userid == 1)` - it is a more elegant solution.

Comment: thank you! it works for counting, but if i want to put a function under a for loop, what is the best syntax to use ?

Comment: you can use it in the function; it does not make much sense though. You are outsourcing to a function the job of a single line of code; not very efficient. But if you must: either make the sum the last operation of the function before the final curly brace (your function will return the last value and end), or call `return(y)` from within the curly braces (your function will return this value and stop execution). These are two slightly different means to the same end.

Answer (score 0):

Your post does not contain a question.
Also, your example is not reproducible without the data.

Despite this, it seems that your problem is `generaldf$userid==1`. By subsetting the dataframe with `generaldf$userid`, you get an entire column (a vector), not the single value that you assumed.

You probably need to learn a bit more about dataframes. Have a look at [a tutorial or two](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame).

PS/ Avoiding the loop as Jindra Lacko suggested, is the method I would use to count occurrences.